# React хуки - общая модель взаимодействия компонентов

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react-lite

Пытаюсь переписать приложение React + mobx с использованием хуков + mobx-react-lite. Поделитесь опытом, как должна выглядеть модель взаимодействия компонентов между собой на примере следующей простой задачи:

```
function App() {  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="frame">
        <Header store={store} />          
        <Table store={store} />
        <IntroButton store={store} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );  
}
```

`Header`, `Table`, `IntroButton` - 'observer' компоненты которые через `props` получали экземпляр `class Store`. Свои события они биндили к соответствующим методам класса.

```
onChange={store.ChangeFilter.bind()}
```

Внутри класса находились observable переменные, которые изменялись. Теперь я изменил описание `class Store` на `function Store()` и столкнулся с трудностями... Из-за того что теперь экземпляр класса не создается, через props передается ссылка на функцию?! Биндить методы теперь тоже не получается... Как в принципе должно выглядеть взаимодействие между компонентами и некоторым менеджером роль которого в моем примере выполняет `class Store`?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, вам нужно создать экземпляр класса `Store` для каждого инстанса компонента `App`.

Для этого используют хук `useEffect`

```
function App() {
  const [store, setStore] = React.useState(undefined)
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    setStore(new Store()) // Создаем инстанс только внутри эффекта
  },
  []) // Пустой список зависимых переменных является эквивалентом конструктора
  ...
}
```